# Спавн обьектов в определенной области на определенном растоянии друг от друга

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет, написал небольшой код спауна обьектов на определенной области с помощью OnDrawGizmosSelected(), он работает относительно правильно, но проблема в том, что почти в каждом случае возникают ситуации, когда обьект выходит за рамки указанной области, и спаунится за ее пределами, подскажите пожалуйста почему такое происходит и как пофиксить, в гугле подобного верного решения не нашел. Вот код

```
<!-- language-all: c# -->


    public Vector3 center;
    public Vector3 size;

    public void setTheBall()
    {
     Vector3 pos = center + new Vector3(Random.Range(-size.x/2,size.x/2),Random.Range(-size.y/2, size.y/2));   
    List<GameObject> balls = new List<GameObject>();
    balls.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("RedBall"));
    balls.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("BlueBall"));
    balls.AddRange(GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("GreenBall"));
//getTheBall возвращает обьект, кторый нужно построить 
    currentBall =  (GameObject)Instantiate(getTheBall(), pos, Quaternion.identity);
    foreach (GameObject g in balls){
        float distance = (currentBall.transform.position - g.transform.position).sqrMagnitude;
        if(distance<10f) currentBall.transform.Translate(pos);
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы же в курсе, что Gizmos работает только в редакторе?

Answer (score 0):

Возьмем область с центром в 0,0 и размер ее 1000,1000.
Ты сгенерил позицию 600,600.
Потом проверяешь нет ли рядом других шаров и находишь, и делаешь злополучный `currentBall.transform.Translate(pos);`
**Translate смещает на вектор pos от текущей позиции.**
То есть у тебя шар стоит на позиции 600,600 и ты перемещаешь его на вектор 600,600, и получаешь 1200,1200 что является выходом за пределы твоей зоны.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, какие есть варианты замены translate?

Comment: самый простой еще раз выбрать случайную позицию где не будет другого шара